# BA in econometrics with mathematics vs BA in econometrics with computer science

Tags: econometrics, banking

Uni applications start quite soon and I have a hard time deciding which degree should I choose.
I’m more interested in mathematics than in CS. However, it isn’t my greatest strength.
I was thinking about working in the investment banking industry in the future. I believe that CS is more useful career wise, but I’m not really sure.
It’s basically a question: which one is better? Mathematics or computer science?

I’d appreciate your every take on this matter :)
Thanks!

Comment: Don't think that's an econ question. In general, investment banking is so broad, it really doesn't matter much what you study. Also, don't study something because you think it might help you in your career. The only thing that helps is being good at whatever you choose.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't belong to Economics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a graduate degree in Finance/Economics, I would suggest mathematics over computer science.
If you are interested in anything else, I would suggest computer science. Career opportunities are much broader with CS than math. (No disrespect to math).